# Subtracting time and having output in years, rounded to two decimals

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I've got a data set with customer birthdays and I'm looking to convert that variable to age in years, rounded to two or three decimal places.  I figured out how to covert the entire column into a timestamp.

One wrinkle is that I don't know how old the data are, but it was posted to a website on April 4, 2019, so I'm using that day as "today" for the purposes of calculating the time delta.

When I try to subtract the two dates, the difference is in days.

Here's what I have and TIA for any help:

The data start with the DOB in day-month-year format, i.e.:  30-12-1993

```
## Making sure all observations are in same format
training_df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'] = pd.to_datetime(training_df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'])


## Checking format of an individual DOB
training_df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'][0]

Out[121]:
Timestamp('1984-01-01 00:00:00')


## Setting "today" as 4-4-2019
data_time_reference=datetime(2019, 4, 4)

data_time_reference

Out[155]:
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 0, 0)


## Subtracting
data_time_reference - training_df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'][0]
```

The output is

```
Timedelta('12877 days 00:00:00')
```

when I need it to be 35.26 (which is 12,877, divided by 365.25)

the data are on Kaggle.com:  https://www.kaggle.com/avikpaul4u/vehicle-loan-default-prediction

Comment: Please post a sample of your `pd.DataFrame` so that we can test things out on our own. :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the output of what one DOB from the dataframe and the output for the date I set as the reference point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following dataframe:

```
  DATE_OF_BIRTH
0    01-01-1984
1    30-12-1993
2    02-12-1997
3    04-07-1963
4    14-04-2000
```

```py
#Convert the values in dates column to datetime object
df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'])

#Set the reference date to subtract
data_time_reference= datetime(2019, 4, 4)

#Get the no of days (integer) after subtracting from reference date
df['days_int'] = pd.to_numeric((data_time_reference - df['DATE_OF_BIRTH']).dt.days, downcast='integer')

print(df)
```

Now, it looks like this:

```
  DATE_OF_BIRTH  days_int
0    1984-01-01     12877
1    1993-12-30      9226
2    1997-02-12      8086
3    1963-04-07     20451
4    2000-04-14      6929
```

Then, divide the days_int column by `365.25` and round to 2 decimal places.

```py
df['result'] = (df['days_int']/365.25).round(2)
```

Final output:

```
  DATE_OF_BIRTH  days_int  result
0    1984-01-01     12877   35.26
1    1993-12-30      9226   25.26
2    1997-02-12      8086   22.14
3    1963-04-07     20451   55.99
4    2000-04-14      6929   18.97
```

Comment: @immaprogrammingnoob, updated the answer. You'll need to convert the original dates column to datetime object using `.to_datetime()` and then follow through. :)